# Dealing With Dependencies in angularjs Testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, browserify, karma-mocha

This is for work (I have permission) so I can't post exact code.

So I have to test controllers of a large module. The module has a large config function with a bunch of controllers for the logic of the different pages.

For the actual application it's loaded with bower, which is irritating since I'm testing with [Karma-Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-browserify) and npm. So the the dependencies are a mess. I basically have to import everything that was loaded from bower.json to package.json.

This is my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: 'resources',
    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: [ 'browserify-shim' ]
    },
    browsers: [ 'PhantomJS' ],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    client: {
      mocha: {}
    },
    files: [
      'tests/assist/test.js',
      'assets/scripts/libs/logger.min.js'
    ],
    frameworks: [ 'browserify', 'phantomjs-shim', 'mocha', 'chai' ],
    port: 8080,
    preprocessors: {
      'tests/assist/controller.js': [ 'browserify' ]
    },
    reporters: [ 'mocha', 'coverage' ],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

So the code below this is my test.js (removing some company-specific names). Also I need to put angular.mock. or it won't work

```
require('angular');
require('angular-mocks');

//Main module needs these
jQuery = require('jquery');
require('angular-bootstrap');
require('angular-recaptcha');
require('angular-ui-router');
require('ngstorage');
require(**The path to the main module**);
require(**The path to a service it uses**);
require(**The path to a service it uses**);
require(**The path to a service it uses**);

describe('Blah', function () {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('blahblah', function () {
    it('sets loading to true', function () {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('controller', {$scope: $scope});
      assert($scope.showLoading === true);
    });
  });
});
```

The main module:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
})();


// Jquery noconflict
jQuery.noConflict();

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngStorage', 'vcRecaptcha', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    ...
}])
.run([blah bunch of dependencies]) {
   ...
}]);
```

The controller (separate fie):

```
'use strict';

myApp.controller('controller', ['$scope', '$http', '$localStorage', 'service1', 'service2', 'service3',
    function ($scope, $http, $localStorage, service1, service2, service3) {
   ..
    }
...
```

As you can see I'm in dependency hell. I got the example test on the angular site to work, the main problem is with the dependencies and myApp not being visible to the controller. **"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myApp" in controllers/services**

If anyone has a better way of going about testing I'm all ears.

Comment: I don't necessarily have a better way of testing it as much as I have a suggestion. Angularjs is not meant to be written with a bunch of controllers, as a matter of fact in Angular2 they did away with controllers entirely because people were miss using them. I suggest looking back at the documents and consider going a more directive central route. My company recently switched from controllers to factories and directives and have noticed a major improvement.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I'm only an intern so I'm just supposed to test a codebase I didn't write, so I can't really do any switching etc. Hopefully estus' answer fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about dependency hell, not about testing also.

The code seems to rely on `myApp` global variable, this is strictly opposite to what Angular modules are for.

`myApp` should be a local variable that is defined dynamically in each function scope

```
(function () {

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [...]);
...

})();
```

---

```
(function () {

var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('controller', ...)
...

})();
```

Comment: wouldn't it also be correct that you could still have your controller in another js file say if you had 10 controllers and wanted to clean it up a bit. You would just reference your module through angular rather than through a global variable like you said above. Ex: angular.module('myApp').controller(.......)

Comment: Please ignore this comment

Comment: @Ohjay44 Sure, it is a matter of preference. It may be redundant for single controller definition but be beneficial for style consistency.

Comment: Hey estus it fixed my 'can't find myApp' problem, thanks! The overall test still isn't working I think there's at least 5 more errors to go through haha. Now I have: null is not an object (evaulating 'document.getElementById("appURL").value.  If you know how to fix it. The error is in a service file.

Comment: @PatrickDD Most likely because the element isn't in DOM, and `getElementById("appURL")` returns null. Keep in mind that root element in Angular specs is detached from DOM, all DOM calls should be preferably mocked. Feel free to post relevant questions on each of the problems.