# Changing HTML tag with jsdom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, mocking, jsdom

I'm testing an angular controller to a huge module and I need to mock the dom to fix the "Controller is not a function" error I'm getting. I need to set:

```
<html>
```

to

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
```

using

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

I get a `nomodificationallowederror`

How do I modify the tag using jsdom? (specifically mocha-jsdom)

Comment: which code are you usong so far that gives you an error?

Comment: Here's my previous question with a ton of the code I have to work with (the error is the last code block with the controller) :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618446/dealing-with-dependencies-in-angularjs-testing

Comment: why don't you just query the html tag itself and set the attribute?

Answer (score 2):

If the element has no parent element, that is if it is the root element of the document, setting its outerHTML property will throw a DOMException with the error code NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR. Have a read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)